# Generic Parcelable CircularArray

Tags: java, android, generics, parcelable

I'm implementing a generic circular array and I would like to make it parcelable. To be able to have the circular array generic, I need to pass the type in the constructor. However, implementing `Parcelable` requires a constructor that only passes a `Parcel`. The two requirements are conflicting and I can't think of a way around this.

This is my attempt, which would fail on the `CircularArray(Parcel in)` constructor as it's missing the type.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by dav on 08/06/15.
 */
public class CircularArray<T> implements Parcelable {

    public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
    protected Class<T> c;
    protected final T[] mQueue;
    protected int curr = 0;
    protected int n;

    public CircularArray(Class<T> c, int n) {

        this.n = n;
        this.c = c;

        mQueue = (T[]) new Object[n];

        curr = 0;
    }

    public CircularArray(Class<T> c) {

        this(c, DEFAULT_SIZE);

    }

    public CircularArray(Parcel in) {

        mQueue = (T[]) in.readArray(CircularArray.class.getClassLoader());
        n = mQueue.length;

    }


    public void fill(T value) {
        Arrays.fill(mQueue, value);
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        mQueue[curr] = item;
        curr = (curr + 1) % n;
    }

    /**
     * Sort the elements in the right order0 and return them
     * @return the queue in the correct order.
     */
    public T[] getAll() {

        int last = curr+1% n;
        int counter = 0;
        Log.i("Circular", "Component is " + mQueue.getClass().getComponentType());
        T[] out = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, n); //new Object[n];

        for (int i = curr; i< n; i++) {
            out[counter++] = mQueue[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<curr; i++) {
            out[counter++] = mQueue[i];
        }

        return out;
    }

    public T getOne() {
        return mQueue[curr];
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeArray(mQueue);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CircularArray> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<CircularArray>() {
        public CircularArray createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CircularArray(in);
        }

        public CircularArray[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CircularArray[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: why do you have `(Class<T> c)` and not `T` ?

Comment: because ``java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance`` requires a Class parameter, that's the only place where I actually need it.

Comment: the type parameter cannot be instantiated directly. Your next question will be "why can't you then use ``(T[]) new Object[n];``, to which there is also an answer but I can't remember ;-) I think the problem is that your ``out`` is then still an ``Object[]`` (due to type erasure at run time), which throws an error when you call it as, for example, ``Float[] f = circularArray.getAll();`` even if you type cast it.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. What type is T?

Comment: declare mQueue as an array of Object. This is how the ArrayList is implemented